# How to change pathname in URL inside http get request

Tags: node.js, express, url, pathname

I'm doing a GET request of some user ID and I really need to get that user profile by ID
app.get('/userID) but I don't want to see the ID in my web URL but the user name, how can I do that? I'm also using Reactjs, I don't know if I have to change in backend or frontend in this case.
Thanks for helping!

**my code - backend:**

```
 const router = express.Router()

 router.get('/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
 let userID = req.params.userId

   .....
})
```

**my code - frontend:**

```
componentDidMount() {

let theURL = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
let userID = theURL.replace(theURL, '/hellotest')

getUserProfile(userID).then(
  response => {
    this.setState({
      userName: response.data.userName,
     ....
    })
  },
  error => {
    this.setState({
    ....
    })
  }
 )
}
```

I've tried with window.location.pathname.replace(theURL, '/hellotest') and doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`req.originalUrl` retains the original request URL, allowing you to rewrite req.url freely for internal routing purposes

```
app.use('/admin', function (req, res, next) { // GET 'http://www.example.com/admin/new'
  console.dir(req.originalUrl) // '/admin/new'
  console.dir(req.baseUrl) // '/admin'
  console.dir(req.path) // '/new'
  next()
})
```

You have to `res.redirect` at the end of your dynamic(/:id) route

```
res.redirect( req.originalUrl.split("?").shift() );
```